# iOS Development: How can I make changes to my app so that it only affects new users?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'd like to make some drastic changes to my iOS app, but I don't want those changes to affect existing installs, since it may cause existing users to complain.  How can I limit the new functionality to new installs only?

One easy way would be to set a global flag at a point in the code that only occurs before the user completes the tutorial, then if that flag is set, use the new code.  Other, more elegant solutions?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Well you could release the changes as a new app. That is what tapulous did with tap tap revenge.

Comment: Whatever you do, it will only delay the complains until they buy their new iPhone, restore their OS or do a clean upgrade.

Comment: fluchtpunkt, that's fine, if they don't backup their data, they'll lose all their game progress and have to start from the beginning anyways, and the whole point of the new changes is that they're improvements for anyone starting at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll set aside whether you *should* do this. Other answerers have said what I have to say about that.

Technically *how* you'd do this is by looking for any data that persists when a user updates the app. So, any NSUserDefaults values you've set, anything you've written to the app's sandbox, keychain values... Any hint you've been here before, and you set yourself a userDefaults flag to only show old stuff. Otherwise, set yourself a flag to only show new stuff.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, that's my thought too.  Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2 different app behaviors, you can just submit a new different app to the App store.  Apple may or may not like "hidden" behaviors that they can't find during review.

Comment: Unfortunately the changes are drastic enough to constitute a "new" app, that would only cause massive confusion.  As far as the Apple review team goes, these changes wouldn't be hidden if they ran the update as a new install, which they're sure to do, unless the tester somehow has the app already installed with the tutorial already completed before they run the update.

Comment: The old behavior would be the one hidden from review.  And just because the approved it before doesn't set a precedent.

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you saying that when Apple approves an app/update, it's not actually approved?

Comment: Just because Apple approved an iOS app before, doesn't mean they'll approved the exact same features or functions in a new app or an update submission.

Comment: In other words, one tester might miss a feature in my app/update that they shouldn't approve, but a different tester might catch that old feature during the review of a new update and deny it?  If so, that's Apple's problem and if they find something that they missed during previous reviews, that's fine, I'll be happy to fix it.  I'm not trying to pull a fast one on Apple.

Answer (score 1):

the most elegant solution that I can think of is letting the user choose.

if your changes are so well delimited that you can use a flag (like you say in your question) to decide which code you run, I would add a setting `useNewUI` which is by default YES unless you detect the app was already installed (read further for more details about this). Then the user can go to the settings (you might also ask them) and decide and at any moment change.

You could decide whether your user is a new or an old one by checking whatever data you are storing in `NSUserDefaults`. At the start of the program, you check, if data is there, then you add `useNewUI` to NSUserDefault with a value of NO, otherwise you add it with value YES.

This approach could based on NSUserDefault could be useful to you even if you disregard the possibility of letting the user choose through a setting.

Comment: Thanks, sergio, tho they're not UI changes, they're UX changes, which is something you don't want the user to have to choose.  I'll definitely use NSUSerDefaults for the flags, tho!

Answer (score 1):

If the app is radically different, then make a new app. Otherwise, anyone who updates will get the new one.

Some existing users may want to have the new one, some may want the old one. This gives everyone the choice.

Comment: Well it's not so radically different to constitute a new app, but different enough to change the UX.  IMHO, it's a bad idea to give users the choice of a UX.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you don't want to give them a choice, then why are you concerned about just pushing the update to everyone?

Comment: For one very fundamental UX axiom: users don't always like change, even when the change is an improvement, but to new users, it won't be a change, it will just be an improvement.

Comment: This is a marketing problem more than anything else. If you can't sell a UI improvement as a UI improvement, you need to work on your selling.

Comment: Marketing?  This has nothing to do with marketing and everything to do with software design.  And who said anything about a UI improvement?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Once you submit an update, all of your users can download it and will have the new feature. If the update is going to annoy your existing customers, it will probably annoy your new users too.

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote, but I have to agree with the person that did.  First, yes you can, in fact it's pretty simple, just read Dan Ray's response, which was more or less the solution I suggested in my question.  Second, I don't know if you've ever been directly involved in UX design or if you just write code to meet whatever specifications you were given, but one of the fundamental UX axioms is this: users don't always like change, even when the change is an improvement, but to new users, it won't be a change, it will just be an improvement.